# Visual Studio Code 'const' can only be used in a .ts file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am getting this error while trying a write a basic JS in Visual Studio Code.

Already tried changing the settings.json ( $workspace/.vscode/settings.json ) but it **doesn't** work.

```
  {
     "javascript.validate.enable": false
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Afaik, You can't define static const within the class declaration. you can try something like this

```js
const MAX_WIDTH = 8.5;

class Books {
  get MAX_WIDTH() {
    return MAX_WIDTH;
  }
}

let myBooks = new Books()
alert(myBooks.MAX_WIDTH);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it is right javascript syntax?

```
class Books {
    static const MAX_WIDTH = 8.5;
}
```

So far as i know, it's not possible to define static property even in ES2015.

You may try some way else, for example:

```
class Books {
    static get MAX_WIDTH() {
        return 8.5;
    }
}

console.log(Books.MAX_WIDTH);//8.5
```